# Is it possible to MS SQL Replication by C# code? If yes, how?

Tags: c#, database, synchronization, replication

I need to replication/sync data between a central database and a few local databases. All databases are MS SQL 2012. I have not access to central database via Management Stdio. It is on a shared host and I'm no sure if accessing replication services on it is possible at all.

It would be very helpful if there were a library or something similar to replicate/sync data between database via C#.

Is there any solution?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done via Replication Management Objects (RMO).

RMO allows programmatic control of Replication via the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.replication.aspx) namespace.

Have a look at [Replication Management Object Concepts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146869.aspx) to get started.

Keep in mind that RMO is deprecated and may be removed in a future release of SQL Server.  I've created [Microsoft Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/774485/rmo-api-deprecated-in-sql-server-2012) to request that Microsoft reconsider the deprecation of the RMO API.  If you feel that it is important, please up-vote it.

Comment: If RMO is going to be deprecated, what will replace it? Sync Framework?

Comment: Found it on the Connect page, it is replacing by Transact SQL.

Comment: Right, which is unfortunate.  I'm unsure what this means for the business logic handler framework.  I think this is a poor decision on Microsoft's part as many people have built applications based on the RMO API.  Please up-vote to have the deprecation of the RMO API be reconsidered.

Comment: Would you please describe what RMO have over the T-SQL?